# remove duplicates from array inside array of objects

Tags: javascript

This doesn't work

```
   const uniqueArray = this.allusers.user_ids.filter((thing,index) => {
              return index === this.allusers.user_ids.findIndex(obj => {
                return JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(thing);
              });
            });
    this.allusers.user_ids = uniqueArray
```

This is the example of my json

```
0:{
code: "sdsdll"
id: 10
type: "New User"
unit: "Amount"
updated_at: "2019-08-20 09:01:24"
user_ids: (2) [2, 2, 3, 4, 3]
value: "12.00"
__proto__: Object
}
1: {code: "ssddl", id: 9, code: "sklsdsd",...........…}
2: {code: "sdds", id: 11, code: "dsfsdf232",...........…}
```

I want to remove the duplicates from user_ids array inside array of objects.

Comment: @Vaibhav none of the solutions shown there will work for objects.

Comment: Remove duplicated from `const user_ids =  [2, 2, 3, 4, 3]` or `const someObj = { user_ids:  [2, 2, 3, 4, 3] }`. I don't see a big difference in how the the given array will be  filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (something like this)*:

**Immutable way:**

```js
this.allusers = this.allusers.map(userObj => {
   return Object.assign({}, userObj, {
      user_ids: Array.from(new Set(userObj.user_ids))
   })
});
```

(*) iterating the object array and mapping each object to a new object with the duplicate user_ids removed by the `new Set(...)` and in the form of an Array by the `Array.from(...)`

**Mutating original objects:** (as @Kaddath mentioned in the comments this keeps other possible existing references to the user objects as it mutates them instead of replacing)

```js
this.allusers.forEach(userObj => {
   userObj.user_ids = Array.from(new Set(userObj.user_ids))
});
```

Comment: The OP's code indicates the original array is to be modified, IMO using `map` (which is not recommended to modify original array) and a clone with `Object.assign` are useless here. A `forEach` with `Array.from(new Set(` should be enough for the task

Comment: What is *something like this?*

Comment: @Kaddath, if that were true the OP wouldn't be using `filter`.

Comment: @JonasWilms the code is quite simple I didn't take the time to explain it in detail, hence "Something like this"

Comment: @Kaddath I noticed OP is mutating the old array hence the reassignment, to achieve the pretended result by an immutable way or to mutate the array is a matter of choice since the OP did not specify any preference

Comment: @Andy there seem to be 2 levels of arrays here, `this.allusers` and `user_ids`, of course the second one is replaced (`.filter`), but remove the `const` and you're left with `this.allusers.user_ids =  this.allusers.user_ids.filter(...);` so the first array is kept.

Comment: @CarlosSá it was just a comment that can be useful not only for the OP but for future readers too. Never said this would not do the job, but in case someone kept references to the users elsewhere and the references are lost after this code, it can be useful to know why

Comment: @Kaddath Yes, I didn't assume other references existing. I've updated my answer to reflect both immutable and non-immutable code. It covers more cases. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to dedupe an array. All you then need to do is convert it back to an array: `[...new Set(user_ids)]`

```js
const data = [{"code":"sdsdll","id":10,"type":"New User","unit":"Amount","updated_at":"2019-08-20 09:01:24","user_ids":[2,2,3,4,3],"value":"12.00"},{"code":"sdsdll2","id":101,"type":"New User 2","unit":"Amount","updated_at":"2019-08-20 09:01:24","user_ids":[4,11,2,2,3,4,4,3],"value":"12.00"}];

const out = data.map(({ user_ids, ...rest }) => {
  const dedupedIds = [...new Set(user_ids)];
  return { user_ids: dedupedIds, ...rest };
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like your `allusers` is an array so you can not call `.user_ids` on it. You can loop through it and process `user_ids` field of each element with [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
let allusers = [{code: "sdsdll",id: 10,type: "New User",unit: "Amount",updated_at: "2019-08-20 09:01:24",user_ids: [2, 2, 3, 4, 3],value: "12.00"},{code: "sdsdll2",id: 101,type: "New User 2",unit: "Amount",updated_at: "2019-08-20 09:01:24",user_ids: [4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5],value: "12.00"}];

allusers.forEach((user) => user.user_ids = [...new Set(user.user_ids)]);

console.log(allusers);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the duplicate values, you can do as follows:

```
var user_ids = Array.from(new Set(user_ids));
```